# Use LINQ to group by one field, sum based on group AND store on Dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I am having a hard time to achieve a result likely because I'm misunderstanding sintax. Here the case:

I have a class that outputs a list. In this list there are two fields that I want specifically. they are ItemID (string) and TotalNet (string). There are other fields but I don't need to work with them at this point, but I do later at code.

The ItemID is the identifier of an Item, it is not unique in the list, so I must group it into one and account how many times this item appears. I achieved that with the following:

```
Dictionary<string, int> dstLoops = list.Select(l => l.ItemID).ToList()
                .GroupBy(x => x).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```

So I get my dictionary with the ItemID, now unique, with the total times that Item appears on my list.

The part that I am struggling to achieve is to sum the TotalNet of all the times the ItemID appears on the list.

I managed to get that using this:

```
var APTotal = from i in list group i by i.ItemID into g select new
            { total = g.Key, totals = g.Sum(i =>Convert.ToDecimal(i.TotalAmountPaid)) };
```

The problem is, it is not a dictionary, and later in the code that will be a headache... well... not much but I would like to avoid it, so I tried:

```
 Dictionary<string, decimal> liststotal = list.Select(l => l.ItemID).ToList().
                GroupBy(x => x).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Sum(Convert.ToDecimal(item.TotalAmountPaid)));
```

Unfortunately it returns me that I cannot convert decimal to System.Func

I have tried some other solutions from this forum and other places, but they usually don't add values to the dictionary.

I can accept two scenarios as a solution:

1. Exactly what I requested above, where I will get a
   dictionary with all Items from my List grouped by
   ItemID and sum of their respective item.TotalNet;

FROM:

> Item1, 10
>
> Item2, 15
>
> Item2, 15

TO:

> Item1, 10
>
> Item2, 30

OR:
 2. a var/decimal/whatever that returns me the TotalNet of the current
    ItemID iteration (I can use a foreach/for later on the code to
    achieve the result I am looking for). So to be clear, this TotalNet
    must be the sum of all TotalNets with the same ItemID from my list
    that I am iterating at the moment. Something like "I'am on ItemID 1,
    go and sum all the TotalNet of ItemID 1 from List".

Honestly... I would like help with the first option, for the sake of learning, but a solution is appreciated whatever the means (sacrificing children in name of an old god to get my output will not be marked as a solution...and possibly down voted).

Comment: You just didnt need the `.Select(l => l.ItemID).ToList()` other than that (and grouping by the `ItemID`) you were almost there

Comment: @Jamiec indeed, honestly I am having issues adapting to the LINQ sintax because everytime I see it, I started thinking on SQL statements and so...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Would something like this work?

```
list.GroupBy(x => x.ItemID)
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, 
                  x => x.Sum(t => Convert.ToDecimal(t.TotalAmountPaid)));
```

Comment: That did worked exactly as I needed and also pointed me some direction to what I was doing wrong. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

@bashis answer is functionally what you are looking for. I thought I could explain the logic a bit.

You have a list with items that have an ItemID as the identifier and TotalNet as the amount, given as a string. You would like to calculate the sum of TotalNet of all elements with the same ItemId, and store the results in a dictionary.

First, we begin with a GroupBy statement. It accepts a lambda used for determining what items in the list to group together. Its return value:

> The GroupBy(IEnumerable, Func, Func) method returns a collection of IGrouping objects, one for each distinct key that was encountered. An IGrouping is an IEnumerable that also has a key associated with its elements.

So you get a collection of groups. Each group contains an enumeration of all the elements which returned the same value for the grouping expression that you entered into the GroupBy statement. In our example, all elements that have the same ItemId. Furthermore, the value of the ItemId used for each group is stored as the group's key.

The final step presented in this solution uses the ToDictionary method. Namely, this flavor:

```
public static Dictionary<TKey, TElement> ToDictionary<TSource, TKey, TElement>(
this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
Func<TSource, TElement> elementSelector
)
```

Here, we need to pass two funcs - one to select the key used for the dictionary, and the other to create the value that will be stored in our dictionary. 
For the key selector, we choose the group's key, which in turn is the element's ItemId. For the value, remember that each group contains all the elements with the same ItemId, so we can just Sum the TotalAmountPaid value (converting to decimal from string) and get the desired result.